# C# loop multiply int to lower

Tags: c#, for-loop, multiplication

I've got the following arrays:

```
int[,] myArray1 = new int[2, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 6, 8 } };
int[,] myArray2 = new int[2, 3] { { 6, 4, 3 }, { 8, 2, 8 } };
```

What I'd like to know how to do is:

- Create a new array with the sum of myArray1 and myArray2
- Create a new array with the subtraction of myArray1 and myArray2
- Create a new array with the multiplication of myArray1 and myArray2

Result of sum would be:

```
int[,] myArray3 = new int[2, 3] { { 7, 6, 0 }, { -4, 4, 0 } };
```

Result of subtraction would be:

```
int[,] myArray3 = new int[2, 3] { { 5, 2, 6 }, { 12, 8, 16 } };
```

Result of multiplication would be:

```
int[,] myArray3 = new int[2, 3] { { 6, 8, 9 }, { 32, 12, 64 } };
```

Can this be done similar to printing out the arrays, with for loops? I tried looking for examples but found none that I could use for my specific problem.

Comment: Short answer: yes, it can be done with for loops. Go ahead and try it,  let us know your particular problem when you get stuck.

Comment: Define "sum", "multiplication" and "subtraction" in logic terms (i.e. "sum would be this plus that ending up here") I don't get how the results are supposed to happen

Comment: I believe you have some values wrong in your examples. Sum of 3 and 3 is not 0, but 6. Subtraction of 3 and 3 is not 6 but 0. And few others.

Comment: Why are the second halves of the sum and the "subtraction" swapped?

Comment: @Alex Element `[i,j]` in the result is the sum/multiplication/subtraction of element `myArray1[i,j]` and `myArray2[i,j]`.

Comment: This is really simple if you just have two arrays of 6 ints instead of arrays of 2x3 ints. If you might have a varying number of size 3 arrays though, I'd recommend using arrays of tuples instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @JonathanMee In general it is a good idea to assume that the example in questions is a simplified version of the actual problem.

Comment: @poke, right so if this is the general case, I'm recommending that he use an array of `Tuple< int, int, int >`s

Answer (score 7):

I usually try to use LINQ, but all I could find uses loops.

```
int[,] myArray3 = Compute(myArray1, myArray2, (x,y) => x+y);
int[,] myArray4 = Compute(myArray1, myArray2, (x,y) => x-y);
int[,] myArray5 = Compute(myArray1, myArray2, (x,y) => x*y);


int[,] Compute(int[,] a, int[,] b, Func<int,int,int> operation)
{
    int cols = a.GetLength(0);
    int rows = a.GetLength(1);
    int[,] result = new int[cols,rows];

    for(int col=0; col<cols ; col++)
    {
        for(int row=0; row<rows ; row++)
        {
            result[col,row] = operation(a[col,row], b[col,row]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

`Func<int,int,int>` is a `delegate` that takes two `int` as parameters and has an `int` as a return value. A `delegate` is just like a "handle" or a "pointer" to a method.

Then you can simply call `operation()` to call the method passed as an argument.

Here I'm using the following lambda expression:

1. `(x,y) => x+y` to compute the addition
2. `(x,y) => x-y` to compute the substraction
3. `(x,y) => x*y` to compute the multiplication

All of these are passed as `operation` argument, so they can be called from inside `Compute()`. The compiler automatically create `Func<int,int,int>` from these lambda.

This way you can use the same `Compute()` method to apply various operations.

Comment: Benoit, would you please explain in your answer, why Func operation takes 3 int values and what the line `operation(a[col,row], b[col,row]);` actually does? This looks pretty neat but I don't understand it completly

Comment: @Serv `Func<int, int, int>` is a delegate which takes two `int` values and return also `int` value. And `operation(a[col,row], b[col,row]);` simply applies this operation on values from arrays. When passing an argument to this method, you simply define what operation should be applied on two input values.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase that, to see if I understood it: `(x+y) => x+y` means `(input(1), input(2)) => (result by specified operation(3))` right?

Comment: Would like to give +1 for trying to use linq, +1 for accepting for loops work better here & +1 for the function injection. Limited to just +1 though sadly. Nice answer though.

Comment: @Serv `(x, y) => x + y` essentially defines a function that takes two ints `x` and `y` as an input, performs the calculation `x + y` and returns the result as an int.

Comment: @DavidArno The problem is that you can't really use LINQ to work multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: I think I just grabbed the idea behind it. I will definetily play around with this, to dive deeper. A huge thank you for trying to explain this to me.

Answer (score 1):

The result at index `[i,j]` is the sum, multiplication or subtraction of the elements in the two source arrays at the same index. So you can do it by simply looping over those indexes and assigning the result value for each cell to the result array.

```
int[,] myArray1 = new int[2, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 6, 8 } };
int[,] myArray2 = new int[2, 3] { { 6, 4, 3 }, { 8, 2, 8 } };

int[,] result = new int[2, 3];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        result[i, j] = myArray1[i, j] + myArray2[i, j];
        //                            ^
        //            change that for a different operation
    }
}
```

If you need all results, you can also just calculate all the results at once, saving you from iterating through the array multiple times:

```
int[,] resultAdd = new int[2, 3];
int[,] resultMultiply = new int[2, 3];
int[,] resultSubtract = new int[2, 3];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        resultAdd[i, j] = myArray1[i, j] + myArray2[i, j];
        resultMultiply[i, j] = myArray1[i, j] * myArray2[i, j];
        resultSubtract[i, j] = myArray1[i, j] - myArray2[i, j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugly compared with Benoit's neat solution.

Comment: @DavidArno It might be “ugly” but it’s straight to the point of what needs to be done to perform this kind of calculation without throwing in some magic that just confuses or distracts people from the actual solution to the problem. And looking at the question, the actual problem seemed to be how to loop over the arrays…

Comment: @DavidArno And being “ugly” (although it’s really just the same thing) justifies a down vote…?

Comment: No, it wasn't justified. So removed.